# Expresión lambda para recuperar datos con propiedades de navegación Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tengo 2 tablas que son:

[image: DiagramaBD]

Estoy tratando de, mediante una expresión lambda, recuperar todos los documentos que pertenecen a un expediente.

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
public static List<Documento> GetDocumentos(Expediente expediente)
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();
        try
        {
            return context.Documento.Where(x => x.Expediente == expediente).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Envío un "Expediente" y lo comparo con con la propiedad de navegación de los documentos sobre el expediente. Pero me tira la expeción:

System.Exception: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Entidad.Expediente'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Tengo un datagrid de Expedientes que al darle click a un expediente ejecuta esto:

```
try
            {
            dgvDocumento.DataSource = DocumentoNG.GetDocumentos(bExpedientes[e.RowIndex]);
        }
        catch(Exception excepcion)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: "+excepcion);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes utilizar propiedades de navegacion para filtrar una consulta con entity framework.

Lo que el error esta diciendo es que solo puedes utilizar [tipos de datos primitivos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table)(Int16,Int32,boolean, String, etc., etc.) para hacer una consulta con entity framework y el tipo `Expediente` no es uno de ellos.

Intenta discriminando la búsqueda por una propiedad del modelo ya sea el id o cualquier otra como por ejemplo:

```
context.Documento.Where(x => x.ExpedienteId == expediente.Id).ToList();
```